# Disable some features in Admin

Tags: wp-admin

I'd like to open my WP based blog to the general public so they can contribute, so I'm trying to lock-down my WP install.

In particular I would like them to be **unable** to:

- edit the slug or assign tags
- send trackbacks
- add custom fields
- enable/disable comments
- add an excerpt
- see the Tools section
- see the Comments section

What's the best way to go about these customizations? Should I roll my own theme or is there some plugin out there that can suit me?

Answer (score 1):

Check Out the Role Scoper plugin: http://agapetry.net/news/introducing-role-scoper/

> Role Scoper is a comprehensive enrichment for capability enforcement and administration in WordPress. Assign reading, editing or administration roles to users or groups on a page-specific, category-specific or other content-specific basis.

**Update**
From your comment, I dug a little further.  This article explains adding custom roles and abilities:  http://www.wphardcore.com/2010/ultimate-guide-to-roles-and-capabilities/.  Seems very useful.

Comment: looks like it could be a useful plugin for such a public site but not for solving the things I was mentioning

Comment: Updated with another link

Answer (score 0):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ucan-post/ ? Maybe with some more customizations on it ?